# Errors with new MVC5 project in Visual Studio 2013.3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Wondering if anyone else has experienced this and what their solution was if so. In Visual Studio 2013 I create a new ASP.NET Web Application, leaving all the defaults as they are

In the next screen I pick MVC, adding folders and core references for MVC but not the other two options. Authentication is left at **Individual User Accounts** and I've unchecked the *Host in the cloud* option, as shown below.

[image: Initial post new project screen]

The project wizard completes and I can see that there are 26 errors in it before I do anything else.

The first fix that removes a bunch of these errors is that the `Views\Account\ _SetPasswordPartial.cshtml` and `_ChangePasswordPartial.cshtml` files contain invalid models so I change those as follows:

[My project name here is *WebApplication1*, substitute your own value]

In _SetPasswordPartial.cshtml: 
From `@model WebApplication1.Models.ManageUserViewModel` to `@model WebApplication1.Models.SetPasswordViewModel`

In file _ChangePasswordPartial.cshtml:
From @model Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.ManageUserViewModel to @model WebApplication1.Models.ChangePasswordViewModel

That drops me down to 4 errors, spread across 4 files

1.
Line 68, ManageController.cs

```
return View(linkedAccounts);
```

The view RemoveLogin doesn't exist

2,3.
There are two errors `_SetPasswordPartial.cshtml` and `_ChangePasswordPartial.cshtml` complaining about not being able to resolve the Manage action but when I debug and visit those URLs in the browser they work fine so I suspect they're in a route table somewhere. I have R# installed so sometimes that can be wrong if that's the case.

4.
The last one is that the `_RemoveAccountPartial.cshtml` has an error on line 15 where it complains about not having a Disassociate action in the Account controller, as far as I can ascertain this is to do with removing other authentication providers to the application.

Now I can fix all these by adding the required code but it just doesn't sit well with me that the templates don't work well out of the box. Are there fresh templates available or has anyone done the canonical write-up on how to get your template humming before you commence work properly on it?

**EDIT 2014-11-13**
I've just applied VS2013.4 and these issues appear to be fixed as part of it. If this is an issue for people then I suggest applying that update.

Comment: I have no help, but did confirm the issue(s) on a clean project (VS 2013 Ultimate (all patches installed), MVC 5, .NET 4.5.1).

Comment: I've searched the project for _SetPasswordPartial and found nothing, same for the _ChangePasswordPartial. Perhaps these are just some left over files? Notice there is a SetPassword view under Manage, same for the other.

Comment: _RemoveAccountPartial.cshtml seems to have matching code in ManageLogins.cshtml (under Manage), so I assume this can be removed as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not know what is the root cause of these problems but after playing with the project the following seems to bring it to a consistent state:

1. Remove `Views\Account\_SetPasswordPartial.cshtml`
2. Remove `Views\Account\_ChangePasswordPartial.cshtml`
3. Remove `Views\Account\_RemoveAccountPartial.cshtml`

All these have counterparts under the `Manage` controller. And finally:

4. Remove the `RemoveLogin()` action method from `ManageController`. Make sure you only remove the GET method (lines 64 - 69), as the POST one is actually used. The list of logins is rendered by `ManageLogins` action.

Comment: I thought that removing these partials would surely break something but it seems to be working okay at first test. Thanks Karel...

Answer (score 3):

Found out it's a known problem:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/04/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-3-rtm.aspx

> 2. When creating a default C# ASP.NET Web Application from MVC, WebAPI or SPA template with individual authentication, generated Views\Account\ _SetPasswordPartial.cshtml and _ChangePasswordPartial.cshtml files contain invalid model.
>
> In file _SetPasswordPartial.cshtml,
>
> @model .Models.ManageUserViewModel
> Should be changed to:
> @model .Models.SetPasswordViewModel
>
> In file _ChangePasswordPartial.cshtml,
>
> @model Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.ManageUserViewModel
> Should be changed to:
> @model .Models.ChangePasswordViewModel
>
> Similar problems exist for generated VB projects as well.
>
> In file _SetPasswordPartial.vbhtml,
>
> @ModelType ManageUserViewModel
> Should be changed to:
> @ModelType SetPasswordViewModel
>
> In file _ChangePasswordPartial.vbhtml,
>
> @ModelType ManageUserViewModel
> Should be changed to:
> @ModelType ChangePasswordViewModel

Answer (score -3):

I confirmed issue also in VS2013 Ultimate Update#3.  Submitted bug report to Microsoft Connect under Visual Studio and .NET Framework section.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment not as an answer. Thank you

Comment: Whilst agreeing with @Jakub and seconding that you should move this to a comment, when you're editing it would you please include the link to the submission?