# Where is the class ManageUserViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a project using ASP.Net MVC 5, EF 6 and .Net 4.5.1 
At some point I needed to change the namespace that the project is in, from "MyTestProject" to "MyRealProject".

After making those changes throughout the web site I now get several errors in a couple of my views.
_ChangePasswordPartial.cshtml can't find "@model Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.ManageUserViewModel" any longer and _SetPasswordPartial.cshtml can't find "MyRealProject.ManageUserViewModel"

No where in the project can I find a file that contains the class ManageUserViewModel. Before I changed the namespace it was found but now it isn't. Why? Where did it go and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 10):

Found out it's a known problem:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/04/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-3-rtm.aspx

> 2. When creating a default C# ASP.NET Web Application from MVC, WebAPI or SPA template with individual authentication, generated Views\Account\ _SetPasswordPartial.cshtml and _ChangePasswordPartial.cshtml files contain invalid model.
>
> In file _SetPasswordPartial.cshtml,
>
> @model .Models.ManageUserViewModel 
>   Should be changed to: 
>   @model .Models.SetPasswordViewModel
>
> In file _ChangePasswordPartial.cshtml,
>
> @model Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.ManageUserViewModel 
>   Should be changed to: 
>   @model .Models.ChangePasswordViewModel
>
> Similar problems exist for generated VB projects as well.
>
> In file _SetPasswordPartial.vbhtml,
>
> @ModelType ManageUserViewModel 
>   Should be changed to: 
>   @ModelType SetPasswordViewModel
>
> In file _ChangePasswordPartial.vbhtml,
>
> @ModelType ManageUserViewModel 
>   Should be changed to: 
>   @ModelType ChangePasswordViewModel

Also posted it here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/27687882/1071698. I don't know what the rules with duplicate questions and answers, please edit as necessary.

Answer (score 4):

_ChangePasswordPartial.cshtml should use something like

```
@model MyRealProject.Models.SetPasswordViewModel
```

Then make sure in the models folder AccountViewModels.cs

The namespace is updated to `MyRealProject`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -3):

CRTL + SHIFT + F , then type in "class ManageUserViewModel" , just that simple

make sure it is set to search entire solution , and it will find the class you are looking for

Comment: I already searched the full solution. It does not exist in the solution.