# Appharbor Deployment

Tags: appharbor

I try to deploy my asp.net mvc 5 application to appharbor via git bash. But when I start the deployment I get the error `The type or namespace name 'ManageUserViewModel' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`.The error is in log file. Does somebody have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Today i was through this error. I found an answer regarding this issue on the following links

[MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/04/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-3-rtm.aspx) (Read the **Known Problems** section )
[StackOverFlow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27687938/1142645).

After doing whatever suggested in these articles if you are still having the error during build or publishing, delete the debug and release folder inside obj folder, then build or publish your project. (Deleting the debug and release folder worked for me after doing whatever suggested in the [StackOverFlow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27687938/1142645), because clean didn't worked for me)